# How to set different header bitmaps for different NSIS installer's pages?

Tags: installation, nsis

How can i set different bitmaps for different pages, say, i want to set a bitmap to be header of license page and another bitmap to be header of directory page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSIS was not really designed to do this, but there is nothing stopping you from tweaking pages in the pre and/or show callback functions:

```
!include MUI2.nsh
!define MUI_HEADERIMAGE

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME

!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE resetimg
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS

!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE setdirimg
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY

!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE resetimg
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS

!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

!macro fixheaderimgafterupdate
;Ugly way to trigger a repaint
GetDlgItem $0 $hwndparent 1046
ShowWindow $0 0
ShowWindow $0 1
!macroend

Function setdirimg
File "/oname=$PLUGINSDIR\hdrdir.bmp" "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Header\orange.bmp"
SetBrandingImage /IMGID=1046 "$PLUGINSDIR\hdrdir.bmp"
!insertmacro fixheaderimgafterupdate
FunctionEnd

Function resetimg
#SetBrandingImage /IMGID=1046 "$PLUGINSDIR\modern-header.bmp" ;This also works, but does not deal with stretching etc
!insertmacro MUI_HEADERIMAGE_INIT ""
!insertmacro fixheaderimgafterupdate
FunctionEnd
```